# Does accessing arrays slow down my function?

Tags: c++, arrays, slowdown

I have 2 functions:

```
unsigned long long getLineAsRow(unsigned long long board, int col) {
    unsigned long long column = (board >> (7-(col - 1))) & col_mask_right;
    column *= magicLineToRow;
    return (column >> 56) & row_mask_bottom;
}

unsigned long long getDiagBLTR_asRow(unsigned long long board, int line, int row) {
    unsigned long long result = board & diagBottomLeftToTopRightPatterns[line][row];
    result = result << diagBLTR_shiftUp[line][row];
    result = (result * col_mask_right) >> 56;
    return result;
}
```

The only big difference I see is the access to a 2-dim-array. Defined like

```
int diagBRTL_shiftUp[9][9] = {};
```

I call both functions 10.000.000 times:

```
getLineAsRow ... time used: 1.14237s
getDiagBLTR_asRow ... time used: 2.18997s
```

I tested it with cl (vc++) and g++. Nearly no difference.
It is a really huge difference, do you have any advice?

Comment: But the two functions doesn't do the same thing, how could you compare them?

Comment: How big are your arrays, and are you accessing elements that are far apart? You could be getting cache misses.

Comment: @Joachim I can compare the functions as they only make a few bit-operations. So they shouldn't take double of the time!

Comment: Also, yes, the four indexing operations will take some amount of time even without a cache miss.

Comment: .... Indexing operations aren't bit-operations. I would expect them to be more expensive, yes.

Comment: @Kyle the both arrays have a size of 9x9. The int values in these arrays are calculated earlier.

Comment: Please show the benchmarking code.

Comment: @MikeMB thank you for the hint, I was just copying the benchmark-code when I noticed that I create 1 more random-value int the diag-function. Without that it is only slightly slower then the other function.

Comment: @Sneedlewoods: Glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question what creates the difference between the execution times of your two functions really cannot be answered without knowing either the resulting assembler code or which of the globals you are accessing are actually constants that can be compiled right into the code. Anyway, analyzing your functions, we see that

- function 1

  1. reads two arguments from stack, returns a single value
  2. reads three globals, which may or may not be constants
  3. performs six arithmetic operations (the two minuses in `7-(col-1)` can be collapsed into a single subtraction)
- function 2

  1. reads three arguments from stack, returns a single value
  2. reads one global, which may or may not be a constant
  3. dereferences two pointers (not four, see below)
  4. does five arithmetic operations (three which you see, two which produce the array indices)

Note that accesses to 2D arrays actually boil down to a single memory access. When you write `diagBottomLeftToTopRightPatterns[line][row]`, your compiler transforms it to something like `diagBottomLeftToTopRightPatterns[line*9 + row]`. That's two extra arithmetic instructions, but only a single memory access. What's more, the result of the calculation `line*9 + row` can be recycled for the second 2D array access.

Arithmetic operations are fast (on the order of a single CPU cycle), reads from memory may take four to twenty CPU cycles. So I guess that the three globals you access in function 1 are all constants which your compiler built right into the assembler code. This leaves function 2 with more memory accesses, making it slower.

However, one thing bothers me: If I assume you have a normal CPU with at least 2 GHz clock frequency, your times suggest that your functions consume more than 200 or 400 cycles, respectively. This is significantly more than expected. Even if your CPU has no values in cache, your functions shouldn't take more than roughly 100 cycles. So I would suggest to take a second look at how you are timing your code, I assume that you have some more code in your measuring loop which spoils your results.

Comment: While your explanation and especially the conclusion seems reasonable, I personally believe that comparing the instruction count of two different functions without seeing the actual assembler code of the benchmark is just too much guesswork to be worth it. And even then there is - as you pointed out - still a lot of uncertainty in the execution times of load and store instructions.

Comment: @MikeMB :-) Perfectly correct. Instruction counts can provide only a very rough estimate. After all, it completely ignores the data dependencies. Yet, even the assembler code by itself can only provide an estimate: Unless the state of the caches is known at each step, we are still left with some guesswork to do. I do these estimate calculations because they can give suggestions how the code can be made faster: It's harder to optimize when you rule out stupid ideas by measurement only without use of reason. Still, the estimates may be wrong, so there is always only truth in measurement...

Comment: I am afraid I dont know how to create or read the assembler-code. But I compiled the program with -O2  with an amazing speed-increase. Both functions now need about 0.35secs instead of 1.15secs.

Comment: @Sneedlewoods Those times are indeed more like what I expected :-) For the assembler code, try compiling with `gcc -S -Os`, it will produce a file with the suffix `.s` which contains the assembler code. It may be a bit tricky to find the relevant part of your code inside, which is why I would suggest putting a single of your functions in a `.c` file before doing this. Note that I recommend using `-Os` when looking at assembler code for a reason: it produces the most readable, least obfuscated output. `-O0` will obfuscate with pointless operations, and `-O2` with pointless repetitions.

Comment: omg, i couldn't believe when I saw it. I compiled for x64 and the functions now need only 0.072 seconds! Can that be possible?!

Comment: @Sneedlewoods That's 7.2 ns, which translates to something between 14 and 22 CPU cycles. I believe that's quite possible for the first function: x64 passes quite a few parameters in registers, eliminating the overhead of pushing/popping them on/off the stack. However, for the second function, that figure looks a bit tight, since the two pointer dereference operations cannot easily be optimized away. If you get such fast times for the second function as well, I would assume that your compiler does some interprocedural optimizations, inlining the function at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Those functions do completely different things, but I assume that's no relevant to the question.</sub>

Sometimes these tests don't show the *real cost* of a function.

In this case the main cost is the access of the array in the memory. After the first access it will be in the cache and after that your function is going to be fast. So you don't really measure this characteristic. Even though in the test there are 10.000.000 iterations, you pay the price only once.

Now if you execute this function in a batch, calling it many times in a bulk, then it's non-issue. The cache will be warm.

If you access it sporadically, in an application which has high memory demands and frequently flushes the CPU cashes, it could be performance problem. But that of course depends on the context: how often it's called, etc..

Comment: Thank you for that explanation! But if i call it 10.000.000 times, the arrays should be already in cache, shouldnt they?

Comment: You're welcome, but I'm not sure you've understood the explanation if that your question is...... In your tight loop test? Of course it's in the cache.

Comment: I found the mistake...1 more random-value in the benchmark for the diag-function. Now it is only slightly slower then the other function, maybe caused by cache and amount of bit-operations. Thank you all.